# SSRS: Variable that runs query based on a (date) parameter value entered by user?

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2008-r2

So I have a report with approx 15 datasets.

The report has a date parameter so the user can run for whichever date they want.

Each dataset has sql logic that basically determines:

```
If @parameter_date does not exist in table 
        then grab the max date from table < @parameter_date
else
        use @parameter date
```

This works and the report works properly as is.

However, I was trying to see if I can have this sql logic in 1 place (rather than 15 times in the beginning of each dataset query) and store it in a global variable, and pass the proper date into the dataset?

When I look at report properties and "variables" it only looks like I can write an expression, not write sql and return a date based on a query.

I'm sure there is an efficient way of doing this, any help would be appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: I'm not sure you want to do this... It won't be that logic in 1 place... you still need to query 15 `dataset tables` in order to determine if the date exists, correct? I think you should keep it as is.

Comment: @WEI_DBA thanks for the response.  I still need to run 15 different queries but I just figured it would take a step out of each query.  It's more of a business date check.  Likely if it's available in 1 table there's data available in all tables I'll be hitting (aka not a holiday or weekend).

Comment: But still your other 14 dataset has to filter out data i.e if without any parameter your dataset returns 500 Rec and you wish to retrieve only those records matching your criteria you need to pass this to your every dataset.